# Creating a flash card set in Javafx

Tags: java, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a program in Javafx + Scenebuilder that has a tab pane for creating/loading a card set and another tab for quizzing yourself using that card set, I want to know how to take input from the user in a series of TextFields for a Title to the flash card set and tie that to the flashcard's Question & Answer(entered in TextFields). The user can then enter the flashcard's Title and hit a load button and then go to the other tab and be quizzed with that flashcard set. I also need to know how to store the set so that it doesn't have to be entered every time the program opens.

Comment: I believe you need to do some research and actually try to do it first.  And ask a question when you have a "specific" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had researched on my own for some way to do this but couldn't find a good way to do this, that is why I asked for help.

A HashMap is what I need, after asking someone that actually would give a straightforward answer this is what I was told.